# MapBasic: skip popup menu dialog to get access to standard "Modify table structure" dialog

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, dialog

I'm trying to develop a small program using MapBasic for MapInfo.
I want to get access to the standard "Modify table structure" (or "Image registration" for raster tables) dialog through "Layer Control" menu using right click on the layer. It may be very helpful especially when you've got a lot of open layers and tables in MapInfo.

Standard way is a little bit challenging:

1. You need to Remember the name of your layer
2. then you go to "Table" -> "Maintenance" -> "Table structure..." -> **Find your table** in the popup menu ->
3. Begin to modify it.

The same thing with the raster registration: you always must to find your table in the popup menu before you can modify it.

I want to skip this popup menu.  You just right click on the layer, choose "Modify table/Raster Registration" option and go straight to the "Modify table structure" dialog. The issue is that I cannot figure out how to get access to these standard MapINfo dialogs. I have found them in "mires
.dll" using "resourse hacker", but I still cannot skip the popup menu.

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome. Including code snippets to show what you have tried as well as any information about what your results were vs. expected results would be helpful.  Take the tour here to get a better understanding of our community: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: In the later versions of MapInfo Pro, you can access the Modify Table Structure for a selected table in the Table List window. Would that help you?

Comment: PS: You can already right click on a table in the Table List and select Modify Table Structure. Just a small FYI

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the built-in dialogs via MapBasic thru the Alter MapInfoDialog statement.

Be aware:

> CAUTION: The Alter MapInfoDialog statement may not be supported in
>   future versions of MapInfo Professional. As a result, MapBasic
>   programs that use this statement may not work correctly when run using
>   future versions of MapInfo Professional. Use this statement with
>   caution.

Have a look at this thread on MapInfo-L: [Loading queries into SQL Select Dialog](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mapinfo-l/mapinfodialog%7Csort:relevance/mapinfo-l/K93BTbSuZ4A/KrNPMUczI2UJ)

You should also have a look at the tool that was made as a result of this discussion: [Query Table Manager v1.2](http://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/code-exchange/download/query-table-manager-v1.2) by Andy Harfoot.